# Sound system is eating away the battery

Tags: power-management, alsa, acpi, soundcard, powertop

In my laptop the sound code is running at 100% even when I am not playing anything. It is causing my palm rest to hit significantly. While I do not face the issue on windows machine where I am using the drivers for IDT. Here is the output of the powertop.

Summary: 0.0 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/second and 0.0 VFS ops/sec

```
            Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
        100.0%                      Device         Audio codec hwC0D0: IDT
         52.3 ms/s       0.0        Process        compiz
```

Is there any solution to decrease the power consumption of the sound device.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: Hello Guys, I have resolved all of power issues in my Ubuntu system using tlp. If anyone facing similar issue I will suggest to check out that utility.

Answer (score 6):

I added the following to `/etc/rc.local`

```
echo 1 | tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save

echo Y | tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller

pkill pulseaudio

pulseaudio --start 

exit 0
```

And it seems to have done the trick...

Comment: This turns the pulseaudio process on Ubuntu 12.04 from the permanent >50% down to 0% in powertop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either the sound driver doesn't support power management or it's not enabled. I've no idea what IDT is, but you can enable power management, for example, for an Intel sound device. The older versions of PowerTop used to suggest it, but the newer one has a menu you can navigate with left/right arrow key - Tunables is the entry you want. Try navigating to that entry and see if there is anything related to the sound card that powertop can tune.

Comment: Thanks mikewhatever. I have tried that options in powertop but that setting is not persistent on reboots. Even on manually setting the low using powertop, Audio codec is at 100% usage. I just left Ubuntu on laptop becuz all these heating issues. Literally you can fry an egg on my laptop palm rest, while on windows it is super cool.

Comment: The heating issues are troubling indeed. Have you tried the `pcie_aspm=force` kernel option? If you want to troubleshoot it further, add some hardware specs to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I am also affected by this issue on debian may those urls help to investigate :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/powertop/+bug/536631

http://rzr.online.fr/q/lenovo