# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS drains my Samsung Series 9 900X3C ultrabook's battery extremely fast. Is there anything I can do to fix that?

Tags: 12.04, power-management, battery, samsung, ultrabook

The title basically says it all. My Samsung Series 9 900X3C ultrabook's battery is in the deep red around barely three hours after disconnecting it from the power - and during most of that time the screen wasn't even on. No heavy lifting, no video playback, nothing. Just a browser with static sites was open.

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Comment: What video card does your ultrabook have? Try using proprietary drivers (exceptif you have an Intel card). It may help reduce consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Check the power consumption by your laptop using powertop and use TLP to fine tune it.

Check out below link how to use the utility:
http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html

This tool greatly helped me to reduce power consumption of my laptop.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Comment: Thanks Qasim to point to that post. Its really a good post.

Answer (score 0):

Look into a tool called [powertop](https://lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/), it should be in your repository. (`sudo apt-get install powertop`). It'll tell you all kinds of goodness, like what's using your power from apps to the fan.

Also, if you have discrete graphics, such as Nvidia Optimus, could it be that the video card is powered up even when you're not using it? If so, try using [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) (in your repo, again apt-get) to control when it's on and off. Or if you don't use discrete graphics, you can probably just turn it off entirely in the BIOS.

EDIT: Looks like there's a documented [bug in Ubuntu/Linux/the driver](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/877560). See these related questions too:

- [Intel HD audio codec power management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97868/intel-hd-audio-codec-power-management)
- [Sound system is eating away the battery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66761/sound-system-is-eating-away-the-battery)
- [100.0% usage by Audio codec hwC0D0: Realtek](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91359/100-0-usage-by-audio-codec-hwc0d0-realtek)

From that, it looks like you need to power down that audio output that's churning away. I'm not sure how, but I would go through that and experiment how. I found those questions and the bug, BTW, for searching "audio codec hwc0d0 powertop" - similar searches might be productive, as well as the discussion on that bug report.

Comment: This is what powertop gives me: http://imgur.com/a/7Cqq0 I have no NVIDIA graphics card in there, it's an Intel Graphics HD 4000. I'm really a complete Ubuntu/Linux novice and don't know what to do with those powertop results now. Any advice?

Comment: I added some further thoughts to my answer.

Comment: Also, on that bug report, some people have been trying bleeding edge kernels and there's a fix, but that's not a beginner-level undertaking.